Having issues integrating google adsense into nextjs
I am trying to add adsense integration to my Next.js application.
​​​
        <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: `
      (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
        google_ad_client: "ca-pub-XXX",
        enable_page_level_ads: true
      });
    `,
            }}
        ></script>

This is my code. I implemented it in the _document.tsx file inside the <Head> component.
However, I still can't get my website verified. I could find threads on internet but was unanswered. I appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need further details.
Note: I just replaced the ad client value. In my original code it is the one in the google adsense.
{
  "name": "chat-room",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.453.0",
    "next": "14.2.16",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.5.4",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.16",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


You should import the adsense script in _document.tsx this way:
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <Script
          async
          src={`https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=${YOUR_CLIENT_ID}`}
          strategy="lazyOnload"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  );
}

Then your ad banner component will look similar to the following:
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const AdBanner = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <ins
      className="adsbygoogle adbanner-customize"
      style={{
        display: 'block',
        overflow: 'hidden',
      }}
      data-ad-client={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
export default AdBanner;

Don't forget to paste your actual client id instead of YOUR_CLIENT_ID
Source article

Hello.I tried this approach too.Unfortunately, I can not get it working in this way too.

can you provide your package.json versions for next.js packages?
to solve your problem we need to create a minimal reproducible example

I just added it to the post
